# Limitation of error code on exception in stored procedure

Tags: informix

I have a stored procedure which is calling a java jar using "SYSTEM" command. This jar is returning an error code on exception using the "exit(errorCode)" command.
If the error code is lower than 256, I can find in the stored procedure the correct error code (in a smallint variable). Otherwise, a random error code is returned. Is there any limitation causing this behavior ?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the OS your are working on? As far I as know , at any *nix OS the limit is 255. After [googling I found this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return status from a SYSTEM statement is limited by the Unix O/S to a value in the range 0..255.  You can't return statuses outside that range; the `exit()` and `wait()` families of system calls only deal in 8-bit values.

Comment: Thanks,Is there any workaround to avoid this problem? like changing the OS or using another function of the "exit() and wait() families" or anything else.

Comment: Well, you could go and create your own O/S that has more flexible arrangements for the exit statuses of commands.  Polish it to the point where it conforms to a (new) standard — clearly, it won't be precisely POSIX — and then make sure it is popular enough that companies like IBM port software to it.  At that point, we might add Informix to your platform and you would probably get the benefit of more exit statuses.  OTOH, that seems like a lot of work for minimal (and uncertain) gain.  Succinctly, no.  The Java program also faces the 0..255 limitation too, of course.

Comment: Windows has a wider range of exit statuses.  I don't use Windows, but it is possible that you can access more error statuses there.